# How to set the selected value of a <select> in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have made an select with diff options in angular 2

```js
<select [(ngModel)]="LineBusinnes" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" id="selLineOfBusiness" class="form-control">
                                 <option  [ngValue]="i.id" *ngFor="let i of lineBusiness" >{{i.name}}</option>
                            </select>
```

Where line businnes is an array.I would like to be selected by default the first option.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Simple `[(ngModel)]="lineBusiness[0]"` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get index in `ngFor` and set `selected` attribute based on it.

```
<option  [ngValue]="i.id" *ngFor="let i of lineBusiness; let idx = index" [attr.selected]="idx == 1">{{i.name}}</option>
```

Comment: Can you try with `idx == 0`?